# New->Android application Project created with a lot of errors(Android 6.0)

Tags: android, eclipse, classnotfoundexception, android-6.0-marshmallow

So when i create a new android application project with **ANDROID 6.0** library i instantly get the a lot of errors in the `MainActivity` code.

Starting with `The import android.support.v7.app cannot be resolved`

To `The method onCreate(Bundle) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method`

When i add the `appcompat.v7` library obviously Some of the errors related are gone but other are coming instead. Like:
`The type android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files` on the package line.

And still `The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method`.

Ok. So add the v4 jar too. Ok. I added it too to the project properties and no errors!

Wait,but when i run the app now I get a `ClassNotFoundException`.

So what the hell android 6.0???

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**
MainActivity.java:

```
package com.minyan.get.dl;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of your Activity (at least the section with imports) and the build.gradle file of your application module. Thanks.

Comment: @fasteque Where can i find the `build.gradle`?

Comment: Do you use Android Studio or Eclipse?

Comment: @fasteque Eclipse. as the tag says.

Comment: Ok thanks, please specify it in the question, since tags are not so visible. My suggestion is to move to Android Studio: it's the official IDE and Eclipse ADT support will end by the end of the year by Google: http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html.

Comment: @fasteque Thank you. But i hate AndroidStudio :(

Comment: As of today, it's the best IDE to develop native Android applications, officially developed and supported by Google. So the best option, specially if you're quite new to Android, is Android Studio.

Comment: @fasteque It rather a matter of taste. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that Android Studio is the main IDE now.
Eclipse is no longer supported.

I suggest switching to Android Studio.

Comment: For real? So why am i the first question of this topic? Android 6.0 is not that new.